# Angular: How to declare a component async

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to find a way to declare a component async and then use it in `.html` as normal component which is declared in `declaration` inside `app.module`

My `app.module.ts`:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: []
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor() {
    this.loadComponent()
  }

  loadComponent() {
    // load and resolve FooComponent component async
  }
}
```

Then in `app.component.html` we can refer to the `FooComponent`

```html
<foo-component></foo-component>
```

All I can find on the internet is "dynamic create component" where we have `ng-template` in `.html` file with some `ref` then use `createComponent` (or `resolveComponent`) API to create the FooComponent programmatically against the ref. But it's not what I expect.

It seems to refer to an Angular component in `.html` file we need to put it in `declaration` statically at build time. Not sure how I can make it dynamically.

`Update`: What I'm actually doing is, I have a lib which is used in multiple projects, the painful part is each time when the lib has new update, I need to re-run npm install for each project which is in different locations (multiple repos). Our company has adopted microfrontend (MFE) (webpack module federation) which works really well, and I'm trying to apply to the lib - converting it to MFE. Doing so, I dont need to run `npm install` each time my lib has update, in each MFE I simply call to the lib to get its latest update at runtime

Please help. Thanks

Comment: How would you expect to reference that component in html if it doesn’t exist yet..? Maybe a better question, what do you actually need? Which problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I added Update section, pls check